# A self-introduction for academic purposes

Tags: word-choice, greetings

I somehow managed to get a MEXT scholarship. Now I've got to make a self-presentation, but I've been struggling with it since I'm more used to reading than writing (which is one reason I could get this scholarship - the tests had no essay or whatever)

In this self-presentation I need to tell my name, the university I graduated and the academic degree, the Japanese university I'm enrolling, field of study and research theme.

I started writing but somehow it felt unnatural, maybe too simple, or maybe out-of-context. So far, it goes like:

> はじめまして。　ジョン・スミスと申します{もうします}。

OK so far, a simple introduction and stating my name.

> 私{わたし}は去年{きょねん}Foo大学の{だいがく} 〇〇 学部{がくぶ}を卒業{そつぎょう}しました。

Not sure how to say "I graduated in X".

> Bar大学{だいがく}で勉強{べんきょう}して修士{しゅうし}を取る{とる}つもりです。

I want to say I want to go for the Master's program of the university. Should I use  研究{けんきゅう} instead of 勉強{べんきょう}? I'll be a research student anyway if I fail the exam to enter the Master's program.

> 専攻分野{せんこうぶんや}は〇〇です。

I'm in doubt whether to use 専攻分野{せんこうぶんや} or 専門分野{せんもんぶんや}. I know there is something crucial that differs these two but I wasn't able to fully understand.

> 研究課題{けんきゅうかだい}は△◇です。 [And then some explanation about the research subject]
>
> どうぞよろしくお願いします{おねがいします}。

This self-presentation should not take more than 2 minutes, but it looks like it won't take even one. Maybe I was too direct? Maybe should I tell something else about myself before finishing?

Comment: I had one of those. You have to introduce yourself at the embassy or consulate or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you are expected to write like a native speaker in this assignment, but "as a native speaker" is the only way I could correct your writing.

First off, I would surely drop 「私は」.  Everyone who reads this will know exactly who you are talking about.

I would use 「[昨年]{さくねん}」 instead of 「去年」 as the latter would sound slightly too informal or conversational.

I might change the plain 「しました」 to the humble 「いたしました」.  I used "might" because this is what I meant in my first sentence above.  I just do not know how "native-speaker-like" you are expected to sound.

「修士」 is barely O.K. but 「修士[号]{ごう}」 will sound better because, strictly speaking, the former refers to the person and the latter, the degree.

「つもりです」 is conversational.  I would recommend 「[予定]{よてい}です」.

「専攻分野」 ＞ 「専門分野」  Use the latter and you will sound like you are already an established professional in that field (rather than a grad student).  I may be being too picky here, though.

Again, 「いたします」 ＞ 「します」 at the end.

Comment: As a non-native speaker and/but an academic in Japan, I want to reiterate that 専攻 is the appropriate term for undergraduate level. It's rude and arrogant (or rude because it is arrogant) to use 専門 about your undergraduate study.

Comment: In terms of 予定です though, the 文部科学省奨学金 does not guarantee that the OP is going to be in a master's program. So I'm not sure if 予定 is the right expression (though I look forward to learning whether you can use it for things you *hope* rather than have a certainty about).

Comment: I am very grateful for l'électeur's answer and virmaior's remarks. I hope this answer can be useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

This introduction sounds fine. As self-introduction for university/work, it is common in Japan to talk about personal stuff like your hobbies, your family ...etc so maybe you can add this.

For some of your questions :

"I graduated in X" > X年に卒業しました

"I want to go for the master program" > 今後の勉強（活動）としてBar大学の修士課程を目指しています

専攻分野 is more specifc for field of study, 専門分野 is specilizaiton in a more general way